# K closest points to origin (K smallest elements) with hoare's partitioning not giving the correct answer for a specific input

Tags: c#, algorithm, quicksort

I am solving this question: https://leetcode.com/problems/k-closest-points-to-origin/

In brief, given a list of points return the K closest to origin where the order within the K does not matter. I am trying to solve this with the quickselect variant using Hoare's partitioning, but for a specific inpput it does not give the right answer and I am unable to figure out why. The Hoare's partitioning logic itself is copied from wikipedia.

Points: [[68,97],[34,-84],[60,100],[2,31],[-27,-38],[-73,-74],[-55,-39],[62,91],[62,92],[-57,-67]]
K:5

```
namespace N
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    public class Solution
    {
        private readonly Random rand = new Random();
        public int[][] KClosest(int[][] points, int K)
        {
            var result = new List<int[]>();
            KClosestHelper(points, 0, points.Count() - 1, K);
            return points.Take(K).ToArray();
        }

        private void KClosestHelper(int[][] points,
                                        int left,
                                        int right,
                                        int k)
        {
            if (left >= right) return;

            var partitionIndex = Partition(points, left, right);
            int leftLength = partitionIndex - left + 1;
            if (k < leftLength)
            {
                KClosestHelper(points, left, partitionIndex - 1, k);
            }
            else if (k > leftLength)
            {
                KClosestHelper(points, partitionIndex + 1, right, k - leftLength);
            }
        }

        private int Partition(int[][] arr, int left, int right)
        {
            //var randomIndex = rand.Next(left, right+1);
            //swap(arr, left, randomIndex);
            var pivot = arr[left];
            left--;
            right++;

            while (true)
            {
                do
                {
                    left++;
                } while (AIsCloserThanB(arr[left], pivot));

                do
                {
                    right--;
                } while (AIsFartherThanB(arr[right], pivot));

                if (left >= right) return right;

                swap(arr, left, right);
            }
        }

        private bool AIsCloserThanB(int[] a, int[] b)
        {
            return a[0] * a[0] - b[0] * b[0] + a[1] * a[1] - b[1] * b[1] < 0;
        }

        private bool AIsFartherThanB(int[] a, int[] b)
        {
            return a[0] * a[0] - b[0] * b[0] + a[1] * a[1] - b[1] * b[1] > 0;
        }

        private void swap(int[][] arr, int i, int j)
        {
            var temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    public class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var arr = new int[10][];
            arr[0] = new[] { 68, 97 };
            arr[1] = new[] { 34, -84 };
            arr[2] = new[] { 60, 100 };
            arr[3] = new[] { 2, 31 };
            arr[4] = new[] { -27, -38 };
            arr[5] = new[] { -73, -74 };
            arr[6] = new[] { -55, -39 };
            arr[7] = new[] { 62, 91 };
            arr[8] = new[] { 62, 92 };
            arr[9] = new[] { -57, -67 };
            var s = new Solution();
            var closest = s.KClosest(arr, 5);
            foreach (var item in closest)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Join(",", item));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

While debugging in the Partition call with left ==3 and right ==7, 3 and 7 get swapped first (so now left is 3 and right is 7). Then left goes all the way to 7, and because of the do while right becomes 6 which is returned as the partition. But this is incorrect since points[5] is [-73,74] and points[6] is [-57,67] (so points[5] > points[6]). I think 7 should have been returned as a partition. This results in the final solution containing [-73,-74] instead of [-57,67]. Can someone please help me understand what part of the algorithm is incorrect/ not applicable to this problem since the wikipedia logic must be correct?

Answer (score 0):

Define `Point` class

```
public class Point
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}
```

now put your points into `Point[] points` and execute simple linq query

```
var closest = points.OrderBy(p => p.X * p.X + p.Y * p.Y).Take(k);
```

Latest version of .NET are smart enough to use a [QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) if you don't need a full sorted collection, so expected complexity should be `O(k log N)`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know linq is that smart. But at the same time, that answer is not satisfying since I've spent a few hours trying to debug this and would like to know what exactly I am doing wrong (hence the specific question)

Answer (score 0):

don't know why the outcome but since this is c# why don't you simplify the code.
define the method returning the distance

```
private static double DistanceToCenter(int[] p)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(p[0] ^ 2 + p[1] ^ 2);
    }
```

then use linq:

```
var s = arr.OrderBy(p => DistanceToCenter(p));
```

this would give you the list sorted by the distance to 0.0, then select the k first to print out.

Comment: Taking the square root is unnecessary computation in this case since I only care about relative distances (not the actual ones). a^2+b^2 comparison already tells me the relative distances. Of course I can sort and take the first K and like Aleks pointed out it may even be optimal, but I want to implement the details myself and hence the very specific question.